# Debian 9.6 on virtual box too slow

Tags: debian, windows, virtualbox

The actual state of my machine:
os: Window 10 64bit
CPU: i5-6400
ram: 32GB
GPU: GTX 1050 Nvidia
Dual monitor 4K

I installed last VirtualBox 6.0.4 and I installed Debian 9.6 on the VM.

VM state:
core: 4
ram: 10GB
gpu ram: 256MB
enalbe: VT-x/AMD-V
dual monitor enabled

I installed virtual-guest-addition with all required packages properly but my VM run very very slow.

I can't understand why because it runs with an average consumption of resources.

I think only to the dual monitor 4k, I can't think of anything else. Unfortunately, this system is unusable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to best use this site. You never gave the specs of the VM. What is "slow"? This will be a difficult issue to solve if there are no specifics. If I remember correctly, Virtualbox will default to 1 CPU core and 512 MB of RAM and only a very limited amount of shared virtual video ram. Compared to the specs of your host OS this would be a much slower system.

Comment: Try reducing the number of virtual CPUs to 1, it may be that virtualbox's new version is doing very badly with that, and problems related to spectre etc.

Comment: I do not think Virtualbox can utilize a 4k display inside a VM without passing the entire GPU through to the guest machine, which would prevent you from using that GPU on the host.  A virtual GPU with 256MB memory does not sound like enough for a single 4k monitor